# Rounded context menus on Visual Studio Community 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Visual Studio IDE doesn't look nice for me, one of the problems are corners aren't rounded. Is there a way to get a rounded corners, like IntelliJ (for example)?

I know about themes and I also know that VS uses its own way to draw graphics, but AFAIK themes cannot change this. So, is there a way extending it or installing some extensions to actually make it look better?

I have seen some images on this [developer blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2022-17-7-now-available/). I see they use preview version of VS, but I still doesn't have this even with preview community version:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnnGt.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8ozR.png

As you can see, the context menu has rounded corners. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I'm using Windows 11, but this doesn't seems to have any effect to VS.

Comment: Those screenshots look like they are from the VS 2022 UI refresh https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-ui-refresh/ . But who knows when we'll get that and what the final version will look like. You could always try Jetbrains Rider to see if their UI is more to your liking.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the link. I was already considering switching to JB Rider, however, it's not free and I don't see reason to buy something, when VS Community is there for free with almost all the features. I hope that the UI refresh will come as soon as possible.